# Find the area product of a core

Tags: transformer, core

I need assistance in solving this question. I am confused as to what formula to use to find the Ap, as i searched and found that there many differen variations to find Ap. I need the Ap to be in cm^4. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks
[image]

Comment: If it's a boost converter there has to be ripple so, when the text says assume negligible inductor current ripple, this makes no sense. You also need to cite where the images you posted came from.

Comment: This appears to be a homework problem; what particular problem are you having with its solution, and what have you attempted so far? Please show your work.